# Xamarin Android c# Viewstub only works once and then getting null pointer

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, viewstub

I am trying to use a viewstub to set my view and it works fine the first time however if I call the method again I get a null pointer exception, Any Ideas why this is happening?

here is my code, on the first time around I call this and it works fine.

```
            ViewStub stub = FindViewById<ViewStub>(Resource.Id.stub);
            stub.LayoutResource = Resource.Layout.overview;
            stub.Inflate();
```

then when I try to do the same one again with a different layout I get a null pointer exception

```
            ViewStub stub = FindViewById<ViewStub>(Resource.Id.stub);
            stub.LayoutResource = Resource.Layout.product_view;
            stub.Inflate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub):

> When a ViewStub is made visible, or when inflate() is invoked, the layout resource is inflated. The ViewStub then replaces itself in its parent with the inflated View or Views.

Your `ViewStub` is replaced by the `Resource.Layout.overview` after you call `stub.Inflate()`. You could use `FindViewById()` to get view in your `overview`, but can't get the `ViewStub` any more.